# Get current ID in lightning component for page Community Salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, url, get

I need help please, I'm trying to get the ID of the current page.
from a page of a community in salesforce, but every time I reload the page to get the ID
this arrives undefined, the URL that I am occupying is something like this: `someurl / s /? idLead = 00QQ000000En8pgG6D`
thanks a lot!

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public Static Lead getLead(String recordId){
        Lead infoUser = new Lead(); 
        System.debug('ID del usuario actual: '+ recordId );
        infoUser = [SELECT FirstName, LastName
                    FROM Lead  WHERE Id = :recordId];
        return infoUser;
    }


<aura:component  implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" controller="ctrlWeddingForm">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="infolead" type="Lead"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <p>Form</p>

        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-form-element">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_6-of-12">
                <label for="disabledInput" class="col-sm-4 control-label titulo_datos">Nombre:</label>

            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_6-of-12">
                <p id="" disabled="true" class="slds-input contenido_datos" type="text" value="">{!v.infolead.FirstName}</p>

            </div>            
        </div>

</aura:component>


({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getinfoLead(component, event, helper);

    }
})


({
    getinfoLead : function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.getLead");
        action.setParams({
            "recordId" : component.get("v.recordId")
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                var infolead = a.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.leadInfo", infolead);
            } else if (a.getState() === "ERROR") {
                console.log("Ocurrio un error");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: is your component on an object record page? it doent look like it - component.get("v.recordId") will only work on record pages in communities

Comment: No Sir, my component is not an object record page, the force:hasRecordId only works for a object record page? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of what you have shared, the reason why `component.get("v.recordId")` is undefined is most likely due to the fact that this only words on object record pages in communities.

If you are not on an object record page, you will need to fetch the id from your URL by  other means.

Comment: To solve the problem, what I have done is get the ID through javascript, the problem is that there is no way to pass the variable to the apex class                                    `var url_string = document.location.href
        var url = new URL(url_string);
        var idlead = url.searchParams.get("idLead");
        console.log(idlead)`